# ASP .Net Identity claims based on role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims

I'm integrating IdentityServer3 in a new MVC 5 website.
For storing and managing users i wan't to use ASP .Net Identity.

For resource authorization i wan't to use claims.
I don't want that for each user each claim for each resource/action must be assigned.

So i'm looking for an solution where i can group claims and assign such a group to an user.

As an example:
There are two resources orders and articles.
Both resources can be created / read / updated / deleted.
I then would have 8 claims (for orders 4 and articles 4) that i can assign to a group and the group to a user (where the combinations can me made by the business).

I can't find a solution / example where i can group claims and assign a group to an user.

Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where are your gruops of user defined ? Active Directory ? your own dedicated database ?

Comment: I wan't to use the default ASP .Net Identity storage